# Magento 2 Delete all Product Images

Tags: image, magento2

I need to delete all product images on the site, then re-do the CORRECT import so all the images are correct.

Is there a quick way to delete all images then do a fresh import without duplicated images?

This is my code:

```
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id);
        $productRepository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
        $existingMediaGalleryEntries = $product->getMediaGalleryEntries();
        foreach ($existingMediaGalleryEntries as $key => $entry)
        {
            unset($existingMediaGalleryEntries[$key]);
        }
        $product->setMediaGalleryEntries($existingMediaGalleryEntries);
        $productRepository->save($product);
```

i get :
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`DBname`.`catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`, CONSTRAINT `CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_VAL_VAL_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_VAL_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`value_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity_me), query was: INSERT INTO`catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`(`value_id`,`store_id`,`entity_id`,`label`,`position`,`disabled`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Any help would be awesome!